# How to omit XML element in C# XML generated from XSD?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

Minoccurs is 0 in the XSD and nillable is true for an element.

But if I don't set the element value, it takes it as null and the record is blanked out on the server. Is there a way to tell it to omit the element from the output XML when some conditions are satisfied but have it for other cases?

```
 <xs:element name='CLS_CD' minOccurs='0' nillable='true' type='xdv:stringLen20'/>
```

Comment: Post your code/context, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), you can control whether the value is emitted by including a PropertyNameSpecified property.

> Another option is to use a special
>   pattern to create a Boolean field
>   recognized by the XmlSerializer, and
>   to apply the XmlIgnoreAttribute to the
>   field. The pattern is created in the
>   form of propertyNameSpecified. For
>   example, if there is a field named
>   "MyFirstName" you would also create a
>   field named "MyFirstNameSpecified"
>   that instructs the XmlSerializer
>   whether to generate the XML element
>   named "MyFirstName".

For example, if you declare the class like this:

```
public class Data
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool CLS_CDSpecified { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(IsNullable=true)]
    public string CLS_CD { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can serialize nothing, an explicit nil value, or an actual value:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));

var serializesNothing = new Data();
serializesNothing.CLS_CD = null;
serializesNothing.CLS_CDSpecified = false;
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, serializesNothing);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine();

var serializesNil = new Data();
serializesNil.CLS_CD = null;
serializesNil.CLS_CDSpecified = true;
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, serializesNil);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine();

var serializesValue = new Data();
serializesValue.CLS_CD = "value";
serializesValue.CLS_CDSpecified = true;
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, serializesValue);
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CLS_CD xsi:nil="true" />
</Data>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CLS_CD>value</CLS_CD>
</Data>
```